# UICollectionView start in particular section

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a UIViewController and in it I have a UICollectionView it being used for a calendar. I added a buffer around today's date and get 3 months before and a year into the future. When the View appears its at the first date (3 month before). Is there a way to make the UICollectionView appear in a later section (for me section 3) on the ViewController displaying?

I tried using scrollToItemAtIndexPath with no animation in the ViewController's viewDidAppear and it worked but you can see the calendar change month, if I put it in viewWillAppear it seems to have no affect.

I did get it working by putting it in viewDidLayoutSubviews but that seems to get called several times on the ViewController appearing, is that the right place to do it?

If it helps I'm using Swift and Xcode 7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  self.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPathToScrollTo)
}
```

Comment: I tried viewDidAppear() but it causes the collectionView to change once the view has finished appearing not just before so you can see the calendar change.

Comment: Sorry could you try it in viewWillAppear? I made a mistake, I'm updating the answer.